# Code conversion

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have got this piece of code from MSDN. It's written in `C#`, encounter a problem when converting it to `VB` windows form.

anybody can help [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/c383ef0b-51b9-489c-9b54-398948e5acaa/how-to-move-controls-at-runtime-in-a-flowlayoutpanel-control)

The problem at

```
foreach (Control control in flowLayoutPanel1.Controls)
{
    control.MouseDown += MyMouseDown;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

C# `foreach` is  VB `For Each`

C# `Control control` is VB `ctrl As Control` here ctrl because VB isn't case sensitive

C# `control.MouseDown += MyMouseDown` is VB `AddHandler ctrl.MouseDown, AddressOf(MyMouseDown)`

See also: [AddressOf Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y72ewk2b%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), [AddHandler statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

So alltogether:

```
For Each ctrl As Control In flowLayoutPanel1.Controls
    AddHandler ctrl.MouseDown, AddressOf MyMouseDown
Next
```

Comment: +1 Nice catch.  I think there must be comparison chart between `C#` and `VB.NET`.

Comment: Why the parenthesis in `AddressOf(MyMouseDown)`? Otherwise, nice to see an answer that is not a blind copy of the crap the developerfusion converter produces sometimes...

Comment: @DominicKexel, you are right. Have done to much C# lately so i always use parenthesis ;-) Edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is your friend mate :) converts pretty well

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Using the site converts the code to:

```
For Each control As Control In flowLayoutPanel1.Controls
    control.MouseDown += MyMouseDown
Next
```

Comment: @user1671639, this will result in the same code as Onam suggested, which will not work.

Comment: @Onam, this just won`t work. See my answer for details. ( -1 )

Comment: There's a lot of stuff that the developerfusion converter does wrong, including events, delegates, using the return value of an assignment, iterator blocks, and probably some more. It's not wrong per se to use such a converter, but this code doesn't even compile...